# Python 3 requests POST request data/params issue

Tags: python, post, python-requests, burp, ordereddict

The issue is that the **data/parameters** in the **POST request** *aren't being sent correctly to be processed by the server*. I've used Burp to check what's wrong and it seems like the parameters are in the request's body as they should, but the thing is that when I go to the *params tab* they don't show there, they're supposed to show there as **body parameters**, not URL nor cookie ones

Everything else works fine, if I edit the request and add them manually it works just fine. Although I would rather have the request headers being sent in the right order, but that's another question, I tried to use an OrderedDict to accomplish that but didn't work

Lastly, one of the parameters has a "+" in its value, it gets encoded like a URL would, in the original request that doesn't happen, so that needs fixing too

Any help would be appreciated, I've been trying for a while

Way of calling requests.post:

```
requests.Session().post(url=url, timeout=timeout, data=payloads, headers=headers, verify="C:\\OpenSSL-Win64\\bin\\certificate.pem")
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured it out, it was the Content-Type, didn't change it when I copied the code for my first request that I edited, silly mistake, but it was hard to spot